# Select из XMLNode Возвращает данные из всего XML

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Есть XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <TablesConfig>  
      <Logs>
        <Table name="T_1" key="id">
          <FieldsSearch>
            <Field>All</Field>        
          </FieldsSearch>
          <LinksDetail>
            <Link table="t_Det11" key ="id" srcKey="id_request" sortField ="id"/>
            <Link table="t_Det12" key ="id" srcKey="id_request" sortField ="id"/>
            <Link table="t_Det13" key ="id" srcKey="id_request" sortField ="id"/>      
          </LinksDetail>
        </Table>
        <Table name="T_2" key="id">
          <FieldsSearch>
            <Field>All</Field>        
          </FieldsSearch>

          <LinksDetail>
            <Link table="t_Det21"  key ="id" srcKey="operid" sortField ="id"/>
            <Link table="t_Det22" key ="id" srcKey="operid" sortField ="id"/>      
          <Link table="t_Det22"   key ="id" srcKey="operid" sortField ="id"/>
          </LinksDetail>
        </Table>
  </Logs>
</TablesConfig>
```

Пытаюсь получить данные конкретной ноды

```
class TableSettings {
        XmlDocument doc;
        string tabSettingsPath;
        XmlNodeList nodes;
        XmlNode node;
        public TableSettings(string TableName) {
            doc = new XmlDocument();
            tabSettingsPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\ExtFiles\\TablesConf.xml";
            doc.Load(tabSettingsPath);
            node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Table[@name='"+TableName+"']"); 
        }
        public List<string> getFiltersList() {
            List<string> filtersList = new List<string>();
            foreach (XmlNode inNode in node.SelectNodes("//FieldsSearch/Field")) {
                filtersList.Add(inNode.FirstChild.Value);
            }
            return filtersList;
        }
}

TableSettings ts = new TableSettings ("T_1");
List<String> list = ts.getFiltersList();
```

Я рассчитываю, что в list  должно быть одно значение "All", но в списке 2 значения.
*node.OuterXml* в Дебаге хранит тест только от секции "Т_1"
Почему в списке содержатся значения от всего XML а не от конкретной ноды?

Comment: Путь начинающийся с `//` отсчитывается от корня. Добавьте в начало точку (текущий узел): `".//FieldsSearch/Field"`. Или пишите просто `"FieldsSearch/Field"`, т. к. это прямой потомок.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: да ответ верный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Путь начинающийся с `//` отсчитывается от корня.

Добавьте в начало точку (текущий узел): `".//FieldsSearch/Field"`.

Или пишите просто `"FieldsSearch/Field"`, т. к. это прямой потомок узла `Table`.